# Implementing HTTPS in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, https, glassfish

I'm trying to use HTTPS in Java EE, for my own login directives and transfering information via a secure protocol. This should be trivial, but I'm having trouble finding a tutorial/guide to do it.

Currently, I'm using Netbeans for all my J2EE work, which uses Glassfish 4.1.1, along with JDK and JRE at the 1.8 version.

I'm basically looking for a comprehensive guide or a quick resume on how to implement HTTPS on a Servlet, so when I access to that servlet (mydomain/#/myServlet) the protocol gets set to HTTPS, uses my own created certificate (I also need help with that), so it encrypts the GET/POST requests, in order to make it unable to read the info (or at least make it a non-trivial thing).

Knowing a list of TO-DO things could be enough; if I know what I have to do, I can look for the information in a proper way. But now, I really don't find anything easy to understand.

Anyone can help? Thank you!

Comment: You look at the wrong place. HTTPS or not isn't decided by the servlet but by the container. Look at glasfish's documentation for setting up HTTPS.

Comment: That's a good answer, a good place to begin. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server will have a port for HTTP communication and other for HTTPS communication. So if you will communicate on HTTPS port the communication will be on HTTPS. So see your server configuration and check the HTTPS port and use that port in the URL.